# Firestore Import Google Sheets Array

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-firestore, google-sheets-formula

How can I get array data formatted into google sheets so I can import it into firestore? See image[image: Document]e below. I have a script to import data from Google sheets directly into my Firestore but I don't know how to format an array with string items like the image below. What is the best way to do this in Google sheets/data format?

[image]

```js
// Create a menu item for 'Export to Firestore' 
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu(' Firebase').addItem('Export to Firestore', 'main').addToUi();
}

function main() {
  // Get the active spreadsheet and its name for the collection name
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = sheet.getName();

 // Get the first row as object properties
 // [ 'comment', 'companyId', 'date', 'email', 'score', 'userId']
 var properties = getProperties(sheet);
  
 // Get the next 100 rows as records
 // [ ['test comment', 'ec24fmJeLA93l5jWPAN0', '1602547200.00', 'bdavis@wftst.com', '3', 'a8waViyRAJWGr2h6Gc3u'] ] 
var records = getRecords(sheet);
  
 // Export to Firestore private key removed for security reasons
  var firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore('XXXXXX', 'XXXXXXX', 'XXXXXX'); 

  exportToFirestore(firestore, sheetName, properties, records);
  
  
}

function exportToFirestore(firestore, collectionName, properties, records) {
  records.map(function(record) {
    // record: ['test comment', 'ec24fmJeLA93l5jWPAN0', '1602547200.00', 'bdavis@wftst.com', '3', 'a8waViyRAJWGr2h6Gc3u']
    // props : [ 'comment', 'companyId', 'date', 'email', 'score', 'userId']
    var data = {};
    properties.forEach(function(prop,i) { data[prop] = record[i]; });
    return data; 
  }).forEach(function(data) {
    firestore.createDocument(collectionName, data);
  });
}

function getProperties(sheet) {
  return sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 6).getValues()[0]; // [ [ 'comment', 'companyId', 'date', 'email', 'score', 'userId'] ]
}

function getRecords(sheet) {
 return sheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, 6).getValues(); 
}
```

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. You want to retrieve the values from Spreadsheet and put the values to Firestore. Is my understanding correct? 2. About `I have a script to import data from Google sheets directly into my Firestore`, can you provide your current script? 3. In your above image, `tags` is shown. But in your Spreadsheet, `tags` cannot be seen at the header. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal? 4. About the value of `date`, in your Spreadsheet, is it the date object? Or the number value is put?

Comment: @Tanaike - thanks for reaching out. Yes I want to retrieve the values from the spreadsheet and put the values into Firestore, you are correct.

Ill put my current script in the post. 

Tags is shown on the screenshot, but it doesn't import into the database like the first screenshot. The first shot where it shows tags is from firestore, and it from our actual application. Not a spreadsheet. I want to be able to import data from a spreadsheet into firestore, in that format. So I need to know how to format the data on the spreadsheet. 

The Date is the epoch/unix date. Firestore reads fine

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand that you wanted to retrieve the values from Spreadsheet and put them to Firestore. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand about `Tags`. Where can the values of `Tags` be retrieved in the Spreadsheet? Can I ask you about the detail of it? I would like to try to understand about it. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again.

Comment: @Tanaike no worries on the language barriers. Not a problem. Tags will come from my actual spreadsheet of data to import. I put in a screenshot that did not have them on it. So I replaced it with a new one. You can see them there. Sometimes a line has 1, sometimes 2, and sometimes 3 (maximum allowed). Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying and adding more information, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for the recommendation. I implemented your script and I am getting an error that states: italic ReferenceError: scores is not defined. I put the following script in and nothing else. `// 3. Send the object to Firestore. const firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore('XXXXXXX','XXXXXXXX','XXXXXXX'); firestore.createDocument(scores, obj);

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for the inconvenience. About `ReferenceError: scores is not defined.` of `firestore.createDocument(scores, obj);` in your replying, in my sample script and your script in your question, `scores` is not used. So unfortunately, I think that this is not related to my proposed answer. I apologize for this. Please confirm and set the correct value of `###` of `firestore.createDocument(###, obj);` and test it again.

Comment: @Tanaike On your answer, you said I needed to set a variable for collectionName - scores is the collection name in my firebase. Am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: Thank you for replying. The error message of `ReferenceError: scores is not defined.` means that `scores` is not declared. So in this case, if your replying of `scores is the collection name in my firebase.` is correct, `scores` should be declared. How about this? Unfortunately, I cannot clearly image your current whole script. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. By the way, although I'm not sure about your current script and your firesore, in your script in your question, it seems that you use `sheetName` as `collectionName`. How about this?

Comment: And also, you can see the document of "Creating Documents" of FirestoreApp at https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript#creating-documents From this, can you confirm the value of `scores` of `firestore.createDocument(scores, obj);` and whether `scores` is declared in your script again?

Comment: @Tanaike thanks for that resource. It helped me fined what was wrong with the error. I didn't have quotation marks (" ") around my score definition. So that got fixed. Now - Have another issue. the import is "successful" however, it loads everything onto one document in the collection. I need EACH LINE on my spreadsheet to be its own individual document. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Tanaike to be clear - 
1) I want each row in the spreadsheet to be its own unique document within a collection. 
2) Tags are the only sets of data that need to be in array on the document. The rest of them need to be just strings.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your new issue was resolved. About your request in your replying, I added one more sample script as the modified script of my proposed script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your request and that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike - this worked and is exactly what I needed. If there is a way you know - that if there is no data within a tag line (for example, a row has only 1 tag instead of 3 or no tags at all), that it will import as NULL as an option that would be great!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You have a sample Spreadsheet like below.

  [image]
- You want to retrieve the values and put them to Firestore as follows.

  [image]
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, I would like to propose the following flow.

  1. Retrieve values from Spreadsheet.
  2. Create an object for sending to Firestore.
  3. Send the object to Firestore.

When above flow is reflected to the sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, please set the variables of `spreadsheetId`, `sheetName` and `email, key, projectId` of `FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId)`, and also, `collectionName`.

```
const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

// 1. Retrieve values from Spreadsheet.
const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
const [header, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

// 2. Create an object for sending to Firestore.
const obj = data.reduce((ar, r) => {
  const temp = {};
  r.forEach((c, j) => {
    let key = header[j];
    if (key.includes("Tags")) {
      key = "tags";
      temp[key] = temp[key] ? temp[key].concat(c) : [c];
    } else {
      temp[key] = c;
    }
  });
  ar.push(temp);
  return ar;
}, []);

// 3. Send the object to Firestore.
const firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);
firestore.createDocument(collectionName, obj);
```

#### Result:

When this script is run, the following situation can be obtained.

From:

[image]

To

[image]

#### Note:

- In this sample script, the sample Spreadsheet I show you above from your updated question is used. So, when your actual situation is different from it, the script might not be able to be used. Please be careful this.
- In your sample Spreadsheet, I understood that the headers of `tags` are `Tags 0`, `Tags 1` and  `Tags 2`. This script is for the headers. Please be careful this. If your actual situation is not correct, please modify the script.
- In this sample script, it supposes that you have already been able to get and put values to Firestore. Please be careful this.
- Please use this script with enabling V8 runtime.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

### Added:

About the following your request in your replying,

> 1. I want each row in the spreadsheet to be its own unique document within a collection. 2) Tags are the only sets of data that need to be in array on the document. The rest of them need to be just strings

How about modifying above script as follows?

#### From:

```
// 3. Send the object to Firestore.
const firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);
firestore.createDocument(collectionName, obj);
```

#### To:

```
// 3. Send the object to Firestore.
const firestore = FirestoreApp.getFirestore(email, key, projectId);
obj.forEach(r => firestore.createDocument(collectionName, r));
```

- In your current script, `collectionName` is used? Or `scores` is used? Unfortunately, from your replying, I couldn't understand about this. So I just modified my proposed script. So please modify the variable name for your actual situation.